# How to read my custom Flurl headers from HttpCall

Tags: c#, rest, logging, flurl, self-signed-certificate

How can I read the custom headers I've put on my `FlurlRequest` throug `WithHeader(string name, object value)` and the `Authorization` throug `WithOAuthBearerToken(string token)` from the `HttpCall` `FlurlClient` settings gives us on `Func<HttpCall, Task> BeforeCallAsync()`?

I've designed our solution with a `FlurlClient` to dinamically setup self-signed certificates and a custom JSON naming strategy, witch is mandatory to comunicate with this third party API.

I'm using Flurl.Http 2.4.2.0

```cs
_flurlClient = new FlurlClient()
    .Configure(settings =>
    {
        settings.HttpClientFactory = new X509HttpFactory(
            _certificateConfiguration.PersonalInfoExchangePath,
            _certificateConfiguration.ClientSecret);
        settings.JsonSerializer = _thirdPartyApiJsonSerializer;
        settings.BeforeCallAsync = async (httpCall) =>
        {
            thirdPartyRequestIdentity = await _appThirdPartyRequestRepository.Insert(
                new ThirdPartyRequest
                {
                    AppRequestId = await _contextAccessor.GetRequestId(),
                    RawContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                        new
                        {
                            Method = httpCall.Request
                                .Method
                                .ToString(),
                            Content = httpCall.Request.Content != null
                                ? await httpCall.Request
                                    .Content
                                    .ReadAsStringAsync()
                                : null,
                            Headers = httpCall.Request
                                .Content?.Headers
                                .Where(h => h.Value != null)
                                .Select(h => new
                                {
                                    h.Key,
                                    Value = h.Value.ToArray()
                                })
                                .ToArray(),
                            httpCall.Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri,
                            httpCall.RequestBody,
                            EnvironmentHostname = await _environmentContext.GetHostname(),
                            EnvironmentAddressList = (await _environmentContext.GetAddressList())
                                .Select(a => a.ToString())
                        },
                        _recoveryJsonSerializerSettings),
                    Timestamp = DateTime.Now
                });
        };
    });
```

I need to log all headers but with this code the only header I'm getting, when applicable, is the `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get them from the `IFlurlRequest` rather than from the `HttpRequestMessage`. In other words, instead of this:

```
httpCall.Request.Content?.Headers
```

use this:

```
httpCall.FlurlRequest.Headers
```

Comment: I've tryed that once, but now I realized I tryed on a call without custom headers :P

Answer (score 2):

To read the headers from an Flurl response, I used this

```
 IFlurlResponse response = await request.WithHeaders(
    new { Accept = "application/xml" }).GetAsync();
 IReadOnlyNameValueList<string> headers = response.Headers; 
 string contentType = headers.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Name == "Content-Type").Value;
 return await response.GetStreamAsync();
```

This gives contentType="image/png".